# How to install the latest version of one particular package

Tags: package-management

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on the intended laptop, with the following package `power-profiles-daemon 0.10.1-3`, which I would like to update to version 0.12 to test if that will allow me to have "performance" as an option on the power management tool. But I don't know how to do that.

EDIT 1: It worked! By doing this, I got the option to enable "performance" on the power management tool. Since the solution worked and it didn't break the system (if possible, I always stick to LTS releases) I will post here and on my other post what I did.

```
$ sudo apt update
...
$ wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/power-profiles-daemon/power-profiles-daemon_0.12-1_amd64.deb
...
$ sudo apt install ./power-profiles-daemon_0.12-1_amd64.deb
...
```

Then I rebooted, opened settings and selected "performance", which wasn't previously available.

Comment: @guiverc The required version of power-profiles-daemon in this question has no missing dependencies in Ubuntu 22.04 which makes it possible to manually install its .deb file and install it without making any changes to the software sources.

Comment: Fair enough @karel, I didn't explore the version numbers of the various *depends* packages, however adding any package from a later release manually, adds risk to the system, as the maintenance & security of that package is on the OP/installer to manually manage, instead of being managed by the system & OS itself.  If they keep records of those changes, they can revert them before *release-upgrade* etc, or potentially have extra burdens then etc (even if security wasn't an issue)... There are costs to that install in maintenance into the future.. that make me prefer user535733's answer.

Comment: Both are correct for many reasons and I know that there is a risk when you install a package that it isn't intended for a particular release, and his solution (than it worked by the way) should't be taken as a magical bullet that will work for every case and every situation. Fortunately, we were talking about just 1 package and a very particular one (power-profiles-daemon). Well, there hasn't been any issues of any kind and I have been using that profile on that laptop for hours, so I have nothing to complain. Cheers.

Comment: @IvnAlfonsoPizarroMontenegro you've taken the security of that package yourself, no issues now & with luck none in the future; but you're using a LTS release which is supported for a further 2+ years (*Kubuntu, 5 years for Ubuntu Desktop*) so what if a *flaw* is detected/fixed a year from now, two years from now... it's on you to detect & correct that yourself. If you monitor the changes/bugs etc. already that's less of a problem, but most users don't watch flaws/fixes that closely. It's a small risk yes, but it's still your burden now for as long as you use 22.04 with the *kinetic* package.

Comment: @guiverc only one way to find out I guess, and by that I mean using the laptop with the upgraded package. If something happens, you can be sure that I will post again on the website. But considering the type of user I am, the type of use I am giving it to this laptop in particular, and the package itself, I think it should be fine.

Comment: You're almost guaranteed to not have issues; my primary issue is LTS releases are usually kept for *years*, and end-users tend to forget what changes they've made, forgetting the maintenance & security effects with prior decisions etc. This is less of an issue for a non-LTS release (*given life is only 6-9 months rather than 2-5 years*) but in this case the package is less of an issue contrasted with other packages.  Please just be aware of the *costs* you've taken on, esp. if you (*or other readers of this page*) try and *apply* this to other packages which have greater security implications.

Comment: Why, please, are you Asking about 'the latest version of one particular package' when you obviously mean either 'any package' or specifically, power-profiles-daemon 0.10.1-3. Doesn't the difference matter to you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To install the power-profiles-daemon version 0.12 package from Ubuntu 22.10 in Ubuntu 22.04 run the following commands from the terminal:

```
sudo apt update
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/power-profiles-daemon/power-profiles-daemon_0.12-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./power-profiles-daemon_0.12-1_amd64.deb
```

This method of manually downloading the power-profiles-daemon .deb package and installing it does not require making any changes to your software sources, so it will not create an unmaintainable operating system that has mixed software sources from the repositories of two or more different Ubuntu releases.

Comment: Yeah this one has [minimal dependencies](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/power-profiles-daemon) that are all satisfied by the versions available for jammy [1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libc6), [2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libglib2.0-0), [3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libgudev-1.0-0), [4](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libpolkit-gobject-1-0). You just have to manually download and install updates in the future.

Comment: +1: Simple, easy to follow, doesn't break the system. I like it!

Comment: It worked and without breaking the system. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the other two answers (upgrade Ubuntu/try using a USB or install the deb file), a third option exists. You can install the software from source.

**See "NOTE:" below before you begin!!!**

First, install the build dependencies:

```
sudo apt build-dep power-profile-daemon
```

Next, locate the [project page](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/hadess/power-profiles-daemon/-/tree/main).

Then, download the software. In this case, clone the repository:

```
git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/hadess/power-profiles-daemon.git
```

Finally, follow the installation instructions from the README.md file (also available on the project page).

```
cd power-profiles-daemon
meson _build -Dprefix=/usr
ninja -v -C _build install
```

Similar to manually downloading the deb file, you will need to manually install updates in the future.

---

**NOTE:**

It should be noted that packages built from source usually install to `/usr/local/` instead of `/usr/`. This allows you to have the default version from the package manager installed along with the version built from source.

However, this source installs to `/usr/` so you will need to uninstall the apt version before you begin:

```
sudo apt purge power-profile-daemon
```

Answer (score 5):

The `power-profiles-daemon` package, version 0.12 is in Ubuntu 22.10.

The simple method is to make a 22.10 LiveUSB, boot it, and test that software in the "Try Ubuntu" environment without committing to an install.

Once you have tested and decided that you REALLY want version 0.12 on your system, you must release-upgrade from 22.04 to 22.10.

- 22.10 is not an LTS release. You must release-upgrade again every six months: 23.04, 23.10, 24.04, etc. Folks who want newer software should be on this path anyway.
- Trying to bolt wrong-version software onto an LTS release is a Very Bad Idea. It creates an unmaintainable [Frankensystem](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian) and often ends in tearful tragedy.

Comment: Great answer. It is actually what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.